# FFMPEG Filter_Complex_Script Cropping by Time

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFMPEG's filter_complex_script option to crop a video in different places depending on the time. I have a file that shows the bounding box of where an object should be and have written a text file called "myscript.txt" that has commands as follows:

```
 crop=x=125:y=190:w=105:h=98
 crop=x=124:y=193:w=106:h=99
 crop=x=124:y=194:w=106:h=99
```

My command line call for ffmpeg is

```
 ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex_script "myscript.txt" -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

This will run fine and produce an output, but the crop window only uses the first line of the file and does not change over time. Currently I have cropping details at the frame level but I can find a way to make this work by second if there is a solution out there.

I am running FFMPEG version 3.4.1 on windows 10.

Thank you!

Comment: ffmpeg doesn't support sending differently-sized frames to the encoder, so even if you got the crop working, the output will have a fixed frame size due to auto-scaling. Your best bet is to run a script/batchfile, which reads the filter line and inserts it in the command, one per frame. You'll have to insert a select filter beforehand to select the frame to work upon.

Comment: Interesting...so what if I specified a specific size output for each frame (which I am perfectly happy with as an output).  Can it be made to run on the script without having to run a batchfile?  I'm trying to run this in python; is there a way to integrate a dataframe of the cropped regions into this command?